# How do I run a Symfony Console command after composer install?

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

My `composer.json` contains the following declaration:

```
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
```

I want to run a custom console command that I have in `src/MyBundle/Command/MyCommand.php`. How do I add this to the scripts to run in composer?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can see how the postinstall hook work for the Sensio DistributionBundle.

As example, this is how you can call the `Hello World` command of the Acme Demo bundle:

**ScriptHandler**

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Composer;

use Composer\Script\CommandEvent;

class ScriptHandler extends \Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler {


    /**
     * Call the demo command of the Acme Demo Bundle.
     *
     * @param $event CommandEvent A instance
     */
    public static function helloWorld(CommandEvent $event)
    {
        $options = self::getOptions($event);
        $consoleDir = self::getConsoleDir($event, 'hello world');

        if (null === $consoleDir) {
            return;
        }

//        $extraParam = '';
//        if (!$options['who']) {
//            $extraParam = ' --who';
//        }

        static::executeCommand($event, $consoleDir, 'acme:hello', $options['process-timeout']);
    }

}
```

You can manage extra param in the json file itself.

**composer.json**

```
"post-install-cmd": [
    "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
    "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
    "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
    "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
    "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
    "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles",
    "Acme\\DemoBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::helloWorld"
],
```

**Tested**

I extend the `ScriptHandler` class of the sensio-distribution bundle of version:

```
sensio/distribution-bundle (v3.0.18)
```

hope this help

Comment: For some reason I can't call "self::getConsoleDir" because it is undefined. Even though I am extending ScriptHandler after I include it with use Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler;

Comment: Hi @juuga which version of the `sensio/distribution-bundle`are you using? I update my answer with this info, check in the `composer.json` and see which version you have (I have the "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0").  BTW you can take a look at the source code of the ScriptHandler class of your version and see how impl, as example, the clearCache command (I copy from it). hope this help.

Comment: you were right, I had an earlier version. I got this working now by checking the file for the correct implementation. thanks!

Comment: Hi @juuga you are wellcome! Strage behaviour in the Sensio bundle instead of compatibility... I will check in the doc of the bundle for further detail about.. Of course, is an helper class not an interface..